# How do I verify a signature signed using Polkadot.js app with rust code

Tags: polkadot-js, rust, cryptography, ed25519

I am trying to write a discord bot using rust/serenity to verify signature signed using polkadot.js app. I use `schnorrkel` crate, wrap the message in `<Bytes>...</Bytes>` and use the [verify method](https://docs.rs/schnorrkel/0.10.2/schnorrkel/keys/struct.PublicKey.html#method.verify) to do this. Everything works as expected for sr25519 signatures. But if the user has generated an ed25519 keypair, this fails.

How can I verify ed25519 signatures? Can I figure out from the signature (or public key) if it has been generated by a ed25519 keypair? I tried with [ed25519_dalek](https://docs.rs/ed25519-dalek/latest/ed25519_dalek/) crate but could not make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JS side actually operates via WASM (if available, which is 99.99% of the cases). When using WASM it uses the same `ed25519_dalek` crate you pointed to.

Specifically [here is the Rust/WASM code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/wasm/blob/e435c1e7b8287dd8ceb5bec566abd6d918e58268/packages/wasm-crypto/src/rs/ed25519.rs#L59-L72) it uses for ed25519 verification.

(There are WASM and non-WASM tests on the JS libs to ensure that they do match, i.e. the WASM verification should align with a pure JS implementation as well)